# Let $ X'$ be a completion of $X$. Is $X'=\bar X$?

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $X'$ be a completion of $X$. Is $X'=\bar X$?

> For any metric space $M$, one can construct a complete metric space $M′$
>   (which is also denoted as $\bar M$), which contains $M$ as a dense subspace.([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion))

What does it mean to contain $M$ as a dense subset? $M'=:\bar M$?

Comment: "The original space is embedded in this space via the identification of an element x of M' with the equivalence class of sequences in M converging to x (i.e., the equivalence class containing the sequence with constant value x). This defines an isometry onto a dense subspace, ..."-From the same article you shared.

Comment: @ThomasShelby thanks for the comment... It wasn't very helpful though, despite possibly containing the answer to my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y, \widetilde d)$ be two metric spaces such that $A\subset X\cap Y$. Then you should note that (in general) the closure of $A$ in $X$ (denoted by $\bar A^X$) and the closure of $A$ in $Y$ (denoted by $\bar A^Y$) need not be the same.

*$M'$ contains $M$ as a dense set* means that $\bar M^{M'}=M'$ (which I think is what you mean). So the closure of $M$ in $M'$ is the whole space $M'$. Of course, we always have $\bar M^M=M$ since $M$ is always closed in itself.

*Remark.* In the Wikipedia article that you mentioned, $M$ is contained in $M'$ up to an isomorphism, similarly to how the rational numbers are contained in the construction of the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks Max for helping an old guy ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. You're welcome! I'm glad to have helped.